# How can I disambiguate a label of a SELECT clause used in a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT
  ...
  (some expression) AS Country
FROM
  Sometable
  ...
GROUP BY Country;
```

- `Sometable` has a column named `Country` (this can't be changed).
- One of the result columns is named `Country` (this can't be changed either).

It works (I want the `GROUP BY` to apply on the result column, and this is the way MySQL understands it as well).

But it issues a warning:

```
Warning: Column 'Country' in group statement is ambiguous
```

So, I want to disambiguate the `GROUP BY`. But the only qualifiers I could find are to specify the database or the table (as in: `Sometable.Country`). It would be fine if the label was used in two different tables, of if I wanted to choose the instance of the label which comes from a table. But I need some kind of `Select.Country` qualifier to specify that the name I want to use is the one from the `SELECT` clause, not the one from the table.

I find it a bit strange that this warning can be removed if I want to select one of the 2 instances of the label (the column of the table), but not if I want to select the other one (the column of the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a,b,c,d, country2 AS country FROM (
   SELECT
  a,b,c,d,
  (some expression) AS Country2
  FROM
    Sometable
    ...
  GROUP BY Country ) s;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the expression you want to group by, you would do:

```
Group By (some expression)
```

I.e., do not use the alias in the Group By. Use the expression itself. The only other way is to encapsulate the query with the expression into a derived table/subquery.